# How to use bind to pass a reference to next()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to generalise some module code so I can reuse a Mongoose callback function.

I need to pass in a reference to the next() function to the callback so the callback can call it if successful.

Here's what my code looks like currently:

```
module.exports = {

    createUser: function (req, res, next) {
        // Make accessing the request body shorter
        var data = req.body;

        // Create the user
        User.create({
            email: data.email,
            password: data.password,
            gender: data.gender,
            firstname: data.firstname,
            lastname: data.lastname
        }, 
        userCreatedCallback.bind(this)); // <-- this is where I want to pass in the reference to next()
    }
};

function userCreatedCallback(err, user) {
    if (err) {
        // Handle error
        }
    } else {
        // Create a Thing for the user
        Thing.create({
            name: user.fullname + '\'s thing',
            createdBy: user._id
        }, function(err, thing) {
            // Call the next middleware
            next(err);
        });
    }
};
```

I also tried `userCreatedCallback.bind({ next: next })` but this also fails. The error I'm getting is:

```
<project-dir>/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:108
  if (this.ended && !this.hasRejectListeners()) throw reason;
                                                      ^
ReferenceError: next is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bind` takes a context followed by a list of arguments. To pass `next` as the first argument to the bound function, you could add it to your invocation of `bind`:

```
// ...
userCreatedCallback.bind(null, next));
```

...  and update the callback signature to support it

```
function userCreatedCallback(next, err, user) {
  // ...
}
```

However, this reads a little strangely against node's `(err, ...)` continuation-passing style. Using a library like [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) might help clean things up ([more detail in an external blog post](http://rjzaworski.com/2013/11/trimming-the-callback-tree)).

Comment: I'd recomment `.bind(null, next)` though. Otherwise it's bound to the module, which doesn't look very useful.

Comment: What @Bergi said. This is the preferred use of bind.